# Ссылки и позиционирование Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как расположить ссылки в горизонтальное положение как вот тут, при этом нужно сохранить моб. адаптацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.footer {
 background-color: #3b3b3b;
}

/* logo-footer */

.logo-img {
 padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

/* end logo-footer */

/* links */

.nav-link {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}


/* end links */

/* social and copy */

.fa-facebook-f, .fa-twitter, .fa-youtube, .fa-instagram, .fa-vk {
 color: #fff;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .list-socials {
  text-align: center;
 }
 .copy {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.list-socials {
    padding: 27px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.copy {
    color: #988060;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}

/* end socials and copy */

/* end footer */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Sell Watch</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    











   <!-- footer -->
   <div class="footer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       
       <!-- logo -->
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="logo-img" align="center">
         <p>Текст</p>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <!-- links -->
       <div class="col-md-6">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Watches</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accessories</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
        
       <!-- socials --> 
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-socials">
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
        </div>
        <p class="copy">&copy; 2010-2016 Copyright Swits Time London</p>
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>







    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Покажите всю картинку, пожалуйста

Comment: @entithat обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Внутри `<div class="col-md-6 links"></div>` я добавил `<div class="row"><div>` и разделил четыре ссылки на две колонки по две ссылки.

```
<!-- links -->
<div class="col-md-6 links">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
            <!-- Тут ul с двумя ссылками -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
            <!-- Тут ul с двумя ссылками -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.footer {
     background-color: #3b3b3b;
}
/* logo-footer */
 .logo-img {
     padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
/* end logo-footer */
/* links */
 .nav-link {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}
/* end links */
/* social and copy */
 .fa-facebook-f, .fa-twitter, .fa-youtube, .fa-instagram, .fa-vk {
     color: #fff;
     padding-right: 20px;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .list-socials {
         text-align: center;
    }
     .copy {
         text-align: center;
    }
}
 .list-socials {
     padding: 27px 0px 10px 0px;
}
 .copy {
     color: #988060;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}
/* end socials and copy */
/* end footer */
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- logo -->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="logo-img" align="center">
                            <p>Текст</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- links -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 links">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    <li class="nav-item active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Watches</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accessories</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- socials -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="list-socials">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="copy">&copy; 2010-2016 Copyright Swits Time London</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Странно что я сам не додумался до этого, наверное надо пойти поспать. :)

Comment: @dragunov_m, да, наверняка!)